# How to block access to specific websites and apps on a Wi-Fi network?

Tags: blocking, wifi-configuration

I have heard that you can block the use of Whatsapp and Facebook on your Wi-Fi network. Please guide me how to do this.

Comment: What kind of Wi-Fi router are you using? What other equipment is it hooked up to?

Comment: I am Using TP-Link router. I am planning to allow all employees to use thier phone with WI-fi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just block all facebook IPs in your firewall.
The problem is that there are many and they might change over time.
In our organization we have a one line script that gives us a list of all facebook IPs that we block in the firewall.

For facebook we use the AS Number. Looks like Facebook has 3 of them AS63293 AS54115 AS32934.
[Search for facebook at the BGP toolkit of Hurricane Eletric Internet Service](http://bgp.he.net/search?search[search]=facebook&commit=Search)

To get all of them we use this command:

`{ whois -h whois.radb.net -- '-i origin AS32934' ; whois -h whois.radb.net -- '-i origin AS63293';  whois -h whois.radb.net -- '-i origin AS54115'; } | grep ^route | grep -v route6 | awk '{print $2}' > /var/www/block_lists/facebook.txt`

That list is generated once a day and shared over HTTP. The firewall/router (pfsense) reads it and blocks all listed IPs.
If you fine with a little bit more manual work you can generate that list periodically yourself and plug it into your router/firewall software.
[Here is the current list for Facebook (07.04.2015 IPv4)](http://pastebin.com/ztkER6nY):

Whatsapp does not have a AS number so you would have to get the IPs of the domain. e.g.:

`{ host -t a whatsapp.com ; host -t a web.whatsapp.com; host -t a www.whatsapp.com; } | awk '{print $4}' > /var/www/block_lists/whatsapp.txt`

The problem with that is that you will need to get every domain and sub-domain.

Comment: What about Whatsapp?

Comment: I've edited my answer, it does now include also an idea for whatsapp